# Message handling in MainActivity (sent from a service with HandlerThread)

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, service, message

I am trying to implement communication between a service HandlerThread and the MainActivity via messages for Android with Kotlin.
But with my current code no messages are picked up in the main thread.
Any suggestions would be appriciated.

This is the code stripped down to a bare minimum:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var looper : Looper
    private lateinit var handler : Handler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        looper = mainLooper
        handler = ActivityHandler(WeakReference<MainActivity>(this), looper)
    }

    private inner class ActivityHandler(private val outerClass: WeakReference<MainActivity>, looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {

        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service running on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}, message received with id: ${msg.what}")
            super.handleMessage(msg)
        }
    }
```

The message is sent from a (foreground) service which runs a HandlerThread via

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).sendMessage(msg)
```

Comment: I don't have much experience working directly with Handlers, so I can't help you there. But you definitely need to remove the keyword `inner` or else every instance of `ActivityHandler` will be bound to and holding a strong reference to the outer Activity instance.

Comment: Is it me or are you overriding an interface's method without implementing the interface. How come the IDE is not complaining?

Comment: Well the binding is kind of wanted in this place since the handler should be tied to the MainActivity. 
The ActivityHandler implements Handler, or which interface isn't implemented?